# Get last url loaded in the iframe in microsoft teams custom app

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have created an custom application in microsoft teams. And loaded our organization website in that tab.
As in the organization website it have multiple routes which user can go while accessing website from tab.

So, is there any way in teams js sdk which can give the last route which was accessed by the user in the tab.

Comment: This is not supported by Teams Client SDK, You can try to store your previous URL somewhere like blob but fetching those URL through teams-js is not possible as what I know

Comment: Can I get the local path of teams from client SDK. So that I can create a file and store user data there.

Comment: Or can I access the teams directory path from client SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure nothing like this exists, you'd need to manage this state your side. If it's an app you control (it's an internal website), you could try save state in a database for the authenticated user, and redirect them when they return. It's possible to use localStorage or sessionStorage, but this will break if the user changes context (e.g. desktop to web Teams, or desktop to Mobile), so better to store in a database server-side.

Comment: Will @microsoft/teams-js sdk help to achieve this?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/using-teams-client-sdk

Comment: I would not expect so - this is something specific to your own requirements, not something that I think a lot of other people would expect. You could certainly submit a request on UserVoice, but if it gets addresses, it's unlikely to be any time soon.